# 3D Visualization with Android | Phonegap

Tags: android, mobile, 3d

I am a junior developer and I just started using Android and some Phonegap features. I would like to know a way to implement a 3D Animation feature with Android and Phonegap.
The animation consists of a 3D Visualization of a product at the user's smartphone. He can flip it up, flip it down, right and left. I know that I need a mecanism in order to create a product texture, then store it into a database and use it later, but the question is : How can I create a product texture and store it based on a real product image? and how to ensure the 3D Visualization feature of the entire combination (object + texture)? Thank you !